# Setting some images in the middle of a screen- row, while resizing window

Tags: javascript, css, html

I building an HTML site for mobile, so the `width` of the window change on every device, I am trying to display 2 images in the middle of row- in the title place, so between the images would be a little space, and while resizing the window I want those 2 images to move automaticly and stay in the middle of the row with the same space. I tried some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<style>
#box {
  width: 55%;
  padding-left: 45%;
}

.imgSize {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
</style>

<div id="box">
<div id="img1"> <image src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sniffels/christmas/256/house-icon.png" class="imgSize"></div>
<div id="img2"> <image src ="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/collection/256/House-icon.png" class="imgSize"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

But as a result one image is covering other,or image covered by the window...any ideas how to set them in a middle on one row.

Comment: To center use `text-aling:center;` or `margin:0 auto;`.

Comment: Having width: 85% and paddin-left: 40% will make your container's width 85+40 = 125%, due to how the box model works. I take this is not intended? Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4RVX/1/) what you're going after?

Comment: No its should be 100%, fixed it...still the issue is how make them stay in place while resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr.Alex..

Try this..

```
    #box {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000;
    }

    .imgSize {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    align:center;
    }
```

Also take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/7nJND/ and drag the middle in between (eighter html or Javascript) and Result. You can see your image at center.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks Venkat...What actually I looking for is showing them horizontally, the problem that from beginning they showen vertically,want to save the space between them horizontally.